# B2B Commerce Promotions Stop Working

Tags: b2b-commerce, summer-23

In early June 2023, we configured promotions in B2B Commerce to work correctly. As we were migrating to User Acceptance Testing (UAT), the promotions stopped working and we notice new promotions functionality.

Salesforce helpdesk stated the Summer Release updates (applied to us on June 17) did not have any promotion changes.

Is anyone else having promotions issues?

Thxs!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.